# How can I replace a fragment used by the tabs in ActionBarSherlock using the Tabs and Pager example?

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock

My question looks similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259869/how-do-i-replace-the-fragment-from-one-of-the-tabs-in-a-tabadapter). However, it is a bit more in general:
Let me try to explain: I am using the ActionBarSherlock with the Tabsadapter and Viewpager. I have replaced all the fragments with my own and now I have a button in one of my fragments which, when clicked on, starts the following onclick handler:

```
public void onAcceptSelected() {

    SherlockFragment addFirstChildFragment = AddChildFragment.newInstance();
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("The new title of the fragment here");
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     ft.replace(R.id.pager, addFirstChildFragment);
     ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
     ft.addToBackStack(null);
     ft.commit();

}
```

The problem is then that the following method in the new fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_childeditor, container, false);
    return v;
 }
```

does not result in actually providing a new visible layout: the tab its contents are empty (e.g. I see a holo white themed empty tab).

Now I have the following questions:

My main question is: "How should I replace fragments within a tab?"
with subquestions:

1. Should I adapt the XML of the Tabs and Pager example and fit it with fragment containers?
2. What is the best practice for using tabs and a viewpager with many fragments? Because I want to use the tabs as my main navigation, but I will have plenty of different fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer resides in the answers to this question
[Actionbarsherlock + tabs + multi fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082163/actionbarsherlock-tabs-multi-fragments/10082727)

Answers to my questions are:
1. No this is not necessary: I can add them programaticllay.
2. I can use fragmentstacks as the example shows in the link above.

Answer (score 1):

Its fairly simple. Just change the fragment associated to the tab like the way you replace other fragment.

```
            Fragment donorpage = new DonorRegistrationPage(); // new fragment for the tab

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, donorpage, "frag");

            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();
```

This should replace the fragment of the tab.